# Rails: Routing Issue, Button to Bring up partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, routes

I have a school page that has tabs when clicked upon are suppose to bring up microposts. The issue is I don't think I am routing it correctly and I feel like an idiot trying to figure this out and not succeeding. If anyone has suggestions please feel free to help me out! Thank you so much!

**Routes.rb**

```
get "/schools/:id/mostrecent_schools" => "users#microposts", :as => "mostrecent_schools"
```

**School Controller**

```
  def mostrecent
    @school = School.find_by_slug(request.referer.gsub('http://localhost:3000/','')).id
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
     end
  end
```

**Tab HTML**

```
li class='StreamTab StreamTabRecent active'>
<%= link_to 'Most Recent', mostrecent_schools_path, :remote => true, :class => 'TabText' %>
</li>

<div id='ContentBody'>
<div id='ajax'></div>
<%= render 'users/microposts', :microposts => @microposts %>
</div>
```

**mostrecent.js**

```
$("#ajax").hide();
$("#ContentBody").html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "users/microposts" )%>');
```

**EDIT**
**Routes.rb**

```
Projects::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :pages
  resources :application
  resources :schools
  resources :microposts
  resources :comments
  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :password_resets
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :users do
      member do
        get :following, :followers
      end
  end
  resources :microposts do
    member do
      post :vote_up, :unvote
    end
  end
  resources :microposts do
    member do
      post :upview
    end
  end
  resources :microposts do
    resources :comments
  end

  get "schools/:page/mostrecent" => "schools#mostrecent", :as => "mostrecent_schools" 

  root to: "pages#index"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can understand, Your routes.rb should look something like this

My final try

Change your routes.rb to this

```
get "schools/mostrecent/new/:page" => "schools#mostrecent", :as => "mostrecent_schools"
```

and in your controller edit this line. If this dosen't work then i give up

```
@school = School.find_by_slug(request.referer.gsub('http://localhost:3000/','')).params[:page]
```

Although this is not the restful way of doing stuff and as far as I know since users belong to schools and microposts belong to users you shouldn't define schools microposts and users as simple :resources.

Refer to [Rails Routing Guide ](Refer to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)for more details.

Comment: I am currently getting this error: 

`Started GET "/schools/stateschool/mostrecent_schools" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-28 23:52:54 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/schools/stateschool/mostrecent_schools"):`

Comment: Change your code in routes.rb to the one i posted in the answer and then check

Comment: Yes I have changed it to the route that you have provided, thank you, but that is the problem I get when I click on the  tab

Comment: I just edited the route 4 mins ago. Make the changes in your routes.rb and then type 127.0.0.1:3000/schools/stateschool/mostrecent in your browser and check

Comment: This is the new error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find School with id=mostrecent):
  app/controllers/schools_controller.rb:13:in `show'`

Comment: Can you run "rake routes" in your terminal and tell me if there is any route matching to schools/stateschool/:id ?

Comment: There is this route `mostrecent_schools GET    /schools/:page/mostrecent(.:format)                   schools#mostrecent`

Comment: and what have you added in :resources for school? in routes.rb

Comment: I added above all the routes I have

Comment: I need to see your routes.rb. Can you paste it somewhere and give a link ? something like www.pastebin.com

Comment: just as i thought your routes are colliding. :resources creates many routes for a particular model. check edited answer.

Comment: modify the route and remove :resources schools and then it should work

Comment: I am currently getting this error :/ `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find School with id=mostrecent):
  app/controllers/schools_controller.rb:13:in `show'`

Comment: I am sorry, keep the :resources schools in the routes.rb.

Comment: Can you push your project onto github? I want to have a look at your files

Comment: the project on github is private but the best i can do is provide for information on this website: http://pastebin.com/LMzXUgR9

Comment: The controller is expecting an id for sunny-buffalo. You need to pass an instance of school or the id with which sunny-buffalo is stored

Comment: If it isn't too much to ask, how can I go about doing this?

Comment: can u tell me what are your fields in the school model ? and what exactly is the id of ?

Comment: Thank you for you help, although it didn't work I appreciate your efforts, I will try to figure it out from my mistakes, once again thank you :)

Comment: I would advice you to make your app as RESTful as possible. It's the only way to make a clean website. The guides at [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) helped me a lot.